# Magento 2: get product through api using product name

Tags: product, api

I want to get product information using product name in Magento 2

Comment: Do you want to use ProductInterface?

Comment: I want to search product name using this - http://localhost/abc/rest/V1/products/table1
using get api

Comment: Gagan, if answer helps you then you mark accepted to those answer, so it will help future readers, you can mark accept answer by clicking (✓) next to answer

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `getList` method with the `name` field specified in the `searchCriteria`:

```
<route url="/V1/products" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::products" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

You request will be looking like this:

> http://yourhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=Matreshka

which generate response with a matching products:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 2083,
            "sku": "Matreshka",
            "name": "Matreshka",
            "attribute_set_id": 4,
            "price": 12.99,
            "status": 1,
            "visibility": 4,
            "type_id": "simple",
            "created_at": "2018-11-06 13:44:51",
            "updated_at": "2018-11-23 13:49:48",
            "weight": 0.33,
            "product_links": [
                {
                    "sku": "Matreshka",
                    "link_type": "related",
                    "linked_product_sku": "1111",
                    "linked_product_type": "simple",
                    "position": 1
                },
                {
                    "sku": "Matreshka",
                    "link_type": "related",
                    "linked_product_sku": "4",
                    "linked_product_type": "simple",
                    "position": 2
                },
                {
                    "sku": "Matreshka",
                    "link_type": "related",
                    "linked_product_sku": "Hat with ear flaps (Ушанка)",
                    "linked_product_type": "configurable",
                    "position": 3
                },
                {
                    "sku": "Matreshka",
                    "link_type": "crosssell",
                    "linked_product_sku": "Ford Explorer",
                    "linked_product_type": "configurable",
                    "position": 1
                },
                {
                    "sku": "Matreshka",
                    "link_type": "crosssell",
                    "linked_product_sku": "Bundle Test Product",
                    "linked_product_type": "bundle",
                    "position": 2
                }
            ],
            "tier_prices": [],
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "description",
                    "value": "Версия возникновения\r\nСчитается, что русская деревянная расписная кукла появилась в России в 90-х годах XIX века, в период бурного экономического и культурного развития страны. Это было время подъёма национального самосознания, когда в обществе всё настойчивее стал проявляться интерес к русской культуре вообще и к искусству в частности. В связи с этим возникло целое художественное направление, известное под названием «русский стиль». Восстановлению и развитию традиций народной крестьянской игрушки уделялось особое внимание. С этой целью в Москве была открыта мастерская «Детское воспитание». Первоначально в ней создавались куклы, демонстрировавшие праздничные костюмы жителей разных губерний, уездов России, и достаточно точно передававшие этнографические особенности женской народной одежды. В недрах этой мастерской и зародилась идея создания русской деревянной куклы, эскизы к которой были предложены профессиональным художником Сергеем Малютиным (1859—1937), одним из активных создателей и пропагандистов «русского стиля» в искусстве. Идея создания разъёмной деревянной куклы была подсказана С. В. Малютину японской игрушкой Дарума, привезённой с острова Хонсю женой С. И. Мамонтова.[1] Это была фигура добродушного лысого старика, мудреца Фукурамы, в которой находилось ещё несколько фигурок, вложенных одна в другую.\r\n\r\nЕго матрёшка представляла собой круглолицую крестьянскую девушку в вышитой рубашке, сарафане и переднике, в цветастом платке, держащую в руках чёрного петуха.\r\n\r\nРусскую деревянную куклу назвали матрёшкой. Сделано это было не случайно. В дореволюционной провинции имена Матрёна, Матрёша считались одними из наиболее распространённых женских имён, в основе которых лежит слово «матерь». Эти имена ассоциировалось с матерью многочисленного семейства, обладавшей хорошим здоровьем и дородной фигурой. Впоследствии оно сделалось нарицательным и стало означать токарное разъёмное красочно расписанное деревянное изделие. Но и по сей день матрёшка остаётся символом материнства, плодородия, поскольку кукла с многочисленным кукольным семейством прекрасно выражает образную основу этого древнейшего символа человеческой культуры.\r\n\r\nПервая русская матрёшка, выточенная по эскизам С. В. Малютина лучшим игрушечником из Сергиева Посада В. Звёздочкиным, была восьмиместная. За девочкой с чёрным петухом следовал мальчик, затем опять девочка. Все фигурки отличались друг от друга, а последняя, восьмая, изображала спелёнатого младенца.\r\n\r\nТехнологию изготовления матрёшки российские мастера, умевшие вытачивать деревянные предметы, вкладывающиеся друг в друга (например, пасхальные яйца), освоили с лёгкостью. Принцип изготовления матрёшки остаётся неизменным до настоящего времени, сохранив все приёмы токарного искусства русских умельцев."
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "image",
                    "value": "/m/a/matreshka.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "url_key",
                    "value": "matreshka"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "gift_message_available",
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "short_description",
                    "value": "<p><b>Матрёшка</b><span> — </span><a class=\"mw-redirect\" title=\"Русская культура\" href=\"https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0\">русская</a><span> </span><a title=\"Древесина\" href=\"https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0\">деревянная</a><span> </span><a title=\"Игрушка\" href=\"https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0\">игрушка</a><span> в виде расписной </span><a title=\"Кукла\" href=\"https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0\">куклы</a><span>, внутри которой находятся подобные ей куклы меньшего размера. Число вложенных кукол обычно - три и более. Обычно они имеют форму яйца с плоским донцем и состоят из двух частей: верхней и нижней. По традиции рисуется женщина в красном сарафане и платке. В наше время темы для росписи разнообразны: это сказочные персонажи, девушки, а также семьи. Стали нередки и матрёшки пародийного характера с изображением политических деятелей. Сравнительно недавно стала набирать популярность матрёшка с изображением </span><a title=\"Портрет\" href=\"https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82\">портрета</a><span> на ней — портретная матрёшка.</span></p>"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "meta_title",
                    "value": "Matreshka"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "small_image",
                    "value": "/m/a/matreshka.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "options_container",
                    "value": "container2"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "gift_wrapping_available",
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "meta_keyword",
                    "value": "Matreshka"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
                    "value": "/m/a/matreshka.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "meta_description",
                    "value": "Matreshka Версия возникновения\r\nСчитается, что русская деревянная расписная кукла появилась в России в 90-х годах XIX века, в период бурного экономического и культурного развития страны. Это было время подъёма национального самосознания, когда в обществе "
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "swatch_image",
                    "value": "/m/a/matreshka.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "botscape_instm_image",
                    "value": "/m/a/matreshka.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "botscape_instm_image1",
                    "value": "/m/a/matreshka.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "in_html_sitemap",
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "botscape_instm_image2",
                    "value": "/m/a/matreshka.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "msrp_display_actual_price_type",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "botscape_instm_image3",
                    "value": "/m/a/matreshka.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "botscape_instm_image4",
                    "value": "/m/a/matreshka.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "botscape_instm_image5",
                    "value": "/m/a/matreshka.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "use_in_crosslinking",
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "botscape_instm_image6",
                    "value": "/m/a/matreshka.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "botscape_instm_image7",
                    "value": "/m/a/matreshka.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "in_xml_sitemap",
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "botscape_instm_image8",
                    "value": "/m/a/matreshka.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "botscape_instm_image9",
                    "value": "/m/a/matreshka.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "required_options",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "botscape_instm_image10",
                    "value": "/m/a/matreshka.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "has_options",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "quantity_and_stock_status",
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "category_ids",
                    "value": [
                        "2",
                        "29",
                        "37",
                        "42"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "news_from_date",
                    "value": "2018-11-23 07:49:48"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "sw_featured",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "country_of_manufacture",
                    "value": "RU"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "size",
                    "value": "167"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "webpos_visible",
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "is_returnable",
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "commenting",
                    "value": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "name",
                        "value": "Matreshka",
                        "condition_type": "eq"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "total_count": 1
}
```

Comment: @Gagan Glad to hear it :) If my answer was helpful, please, accept it.