# how to create custom rest api for getting the list of all products with specific columns in magneto 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, products

```
 Create a custom Rest API product based which just includes the following.
• Product Name
• Product URL
• Product image (media URL)
• Product Price
• Product SKU
• Product Qty
• Product Stock Status
```

what should be the code ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2: get product through api using product name](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256366/magento-2-get-product-through-api-using-product-name)

Comment: no it doesn't ans my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all follow the link : https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-custom-rest-api-in-magento-2/
To make the custom api.

After that modify the code.
Replace the code of Custom.php file from the Below File

> app/code/Meetanshi/CustomApi/Model/Api/Custom.php

```
<?php

namespace Meetanshi\CustomApi\Model\Api;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Custom
{
    protected $logger;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollection;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
     */
    protected $stockRegistry;
    protected $selectedStore = 1;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollection,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */

    public function getPost($value)
    {
        try {
            // Your Code here
            $productData = [];
            $productCollection = $this->productCollection->create()->getAllIds();
            foreach ($productCollection as $id) {
                $product = $this->productRepository->getById($id);
                $productImages = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
                $mainImage = $product->getData('image');
                $images = ['main_image' => [], 'extra_images' => []];
                if ($productImages->getSize() > 0) {
                    foreach ($productImages as $image) {
                        if ($mainImage == $image->getFile()) {
                            $images['main_image'][] = $image->getUrl();
                        } else {
                            $images['extra_images'][] = $image->getUrl();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Product data
                $productData[$id] = [
                    'Name' => $product->getName(),
                    'Url' => $product->getProductUrl(),
                    'Price' => $product->getPrice(),
                    'Sku' => $product->getSku(),
                    'Qty' => $this->getInventory($product),
                    'Stock_Status' => $this->getStockStatus($product),
                    'Images' => $images
                ];
            }
            $response = ['success' => true, 'message' => 'Success', 'data' => $productData];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $response = ['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage(), 'data' => []];
            $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }
        $returnArray = json_encode($response);
        return $returnArray;
    }

    /**
     * @param $productObject
     * @return float
     */
    public function getInventory($productObject)
    {
        $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem(
            $productObject->getId(),
            $this->selectedStore
        );
        return $stockItem->getQty();
    }

    /**
     * @param $productObject
     * @return float
     */
    public function getStockStatus($productObject)
    {
        $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem(
            $productObject->getId(),
            $this->selectedStore
        );
        return $stockItem->getManageStock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but iam getting thw error Call to a member function getName() on bool .. what should i do?

Comment: check the product data, by var_dump($product);

Comment: i added dd(var_dump($product)) in the foreach of getPost method it is priniting some stuff like : ory":protected]=> NULL ["_cacheTag":protected]=> bool(false) ["_eventPrefix":protected]=> string(15) "catalog_product" ["_eventObject":protected]=> string(7) "product" ["_canAffectOptions":protected]=> bool(false) ["_typeInstance":protected]=> NULL ["_linkInstance":protected]=> object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link\Proxy)#942 (31) { ["_objectManager":protected]=> object(Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager)#50 (3) { ["_factory":protected]=> object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\C....

Comment: I have modified the code above, Please check and let me know.
Also do check in magento that whether the products are there or not.

Comment: products are in gr8 amount ... now api just keeps loading

Comment: ![CDATA[ Fatal Error: 'Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5242880 bytes)' in '/var/www/html/UFS/FSD/Integration/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/StockRegistryStorage.php' on line 117 ]]>

Comment: remove the vardump or print_r

Comment: i have done that already

Comment: it just keeps loading and that return memory issue mentioned above

Comment: $productCollection = $this->productCollection->create()->setPageSize(10)->getAllIds();
replace this line to load the data for 10 products and then check it

Comment: still the same issue keeps loading

Comment: any help after this?

Comment: comment the lines $this->getInventory($product);,$this->getStockStatus($product); pass the static value in the array to check it.

Comment: static valu in which array?

Comment: $productData[$id] = [
                    'Name' => $product->getName(),
                    'Url' => $product->getProductUrl(),
                    'Price' => $product->getPrice(),
                    'Sku' => $product->getSku(),
                    'Qty' => $this->getInventory($product),
                    'Stock_Status' => $this->getStockStatus($product),
                    'Images' => $images
                ]; before this line of code i wrote dd($product->getName(); and it prints 1 product name which means logic is working but when i remove the this it loads and loads

Comment: $productData[$id] = [
                'Name' => $product->getName(),
                'Url' => $product->getProductUrl(),
                'Price' => $product->getPrice(),
                'Sku' => $product->getSku(),
                //'Qty' => $this->getInventory($product),
                //'Stock_Status' => $this->getStockStatus($product),
                'Images' => $images
            ];
Try this

Comment: in this case it still loadss :(

Comment: can u help me with this quest too ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/354212/how-to-include-extension-attributes-in-rest-api-call-of-products

Comment: sure let me check